# Wrong URL on search with $wp_query with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code from a developer that uses custom pagination for displaying pages for search results. Once the search is run, the script seems to wrongly generate urls for next search pages (as of 2 page).

The url adds title of one of the documents, retrieved during search, before "..../page/2", so like that:

> www.website.com/document/title_of_one_retrieved_in_page_1_documents/page/2

I am just a novice in WP, so any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to see the contents of the `ps_pagination()` function so we can help (which, from the name, sounds just like a custom function either written by the developer himself/herself or copied from somewhere.)

Comment: dear hector, added - again as picture

Comment: Just to confirm, is that the entire code @Anna?

Comment: @Hector, it was not (:-/) - i uploaded the whole code now.

Comment: Thanks. Alright, so the issue happens only when the user runs a search on your site, correct? It works normally otherwise?

Comment: yes, only when the search is run and when the search result is to be displayed on more than one page

Comment: Alright, please have a look at the answer below and if it helped consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have any further questions (that are directly related to this issue) don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Where's the code to your question? Why did you delete it?

Comment: @Nico, the question was answered - it was a customised code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the code you'll notice that it only checks if we're viewing a category/tag/taxonomy archive, or if it's a date archive, or if it's the author archive. It doesn't take into account search queries, hence the issue with the URLs you're seeing now.

Adding this to the function will (probably) do the trick:

```
if ( is_search() ) :
    $base_url = get_search_link();
endif;
```

So now your function looks like this:

```
function ps_pagination($base_url = '') {
    global $wp_query;

    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged      = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $max        = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    wp_reset_query();

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if(!$base_url) : 
        $base_url = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
    endif;

    if(is_tax() || is_category()) : 
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $base_url = get_term_link( $term->name, $term->taxonomy ); 
    endif;

    if(is_date()) :  
        $base_url = get_month_link( get_the_date('Y'), get_the_date('m') ); 
    endif;

    if(is_author()) : 
        $authorObj = get_user_by( 'slug', $author );
        $base_url =  get_author_posts_url( false, $authorObj->ID, $author ); 
    endif;

    if (is_search()) :
        $base_url = get_search_link();
    endif;

    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    if(is_page() || is_single()) :
        $base_url = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
    endif; 

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul class="pagination">' . "\n";

    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            $link = "<";
        else
            $link = 1;

        printf( '<li%s><a class="psAjax" href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, $base_url, $link );
    }

    sort( $links );

    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="current"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a class="psAjax" href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, $base_url . 'page/' . $link, $link );
    }

    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {

        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            $link = '>';
        else 
            $link = $max;

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a class="psAjax" href="%s" %s data-paged="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, $base_url . 'page/' . $max,'', $max, $link );
    }

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
}
```

Give that a shot and let me know how it goes, alright?

Comment: unfortunately, adding the is_search did not work - it gives correct url path (...search/guide/page/2 - searched for "Guide") but directs me to an empty 2nd page  with no results displayed:-/

Comment: That's odd. I tested it and it worked just fine for me. Maybe it has to do with your site's permalink structure? Which one are you using?

Comment: (Still, you should accept the answer because the original issue, "wrong URL path", has been resolved. It seems you have a different problem now.)

Comment: the permalink structure is  "Post name: https://www.website.org/sample-post/". And I did just accept the answer :) thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Don't worry. If you can, please share your site's URL so I can have a look and help diagnose the problem.

Comment: The site won't load for me, the connection is timing out. I'm guessing its access has been restricted? (or maybe it's my Internet acting up, idk).

Comment: That one does load, so yes the staging site is probably access restricted.

Comment: @Anna will your search only display content from `document` posts?

Comment: @Hector, do you mean the_content()? if so, then yes :)

Comment: I've been thinking about the problem and it seems as if the post type isn't being set correctly when performing a search. I noticed that if you visit `website.org/?s=guide` (without the `post_type` parameter) the same issue happens (empty results page) so it might be an issue with the theme and not with the pagination script itself. You'll have to ask your developer (assuming it's not you) to have a look at this.

Comment: @hector: thanks for putting your time and effort to identify possible cause of the issue. Much appreciated!